# Ui-router StateService.target

Tags: angular-ui-router, target

Hi I was wondering about handle errors, when I get reject from resolve. If i got error from testService, I'd like to handle error globally :

```
            .state('test.one', {

            url: "/test/:id",
            views: {
                'content': {
                    component: 'test',
                }
            },

            resolve: {

                testItem: ['$q','testService','$state', function ($q,testService,$state) {

                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                     testService.get().then(function (test) {
                        deferred.resolve(test);
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                         error.redirect = "nameState";
                         error.param = ={};
                         deferred.reject(error);
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                }],

            }
        })
```

I use  $transitionsProvider.onError for globally handle. I want use targetService but it's not working, but simply state.go working fine. Do you have any solution ?

I wrote sth like this:

```
        $transitionsProvider.onError({to: 'test.**'}, function (trans) {
            var $state = trans.router.stateService;
            var errors = trans.error();
            if (errors && _.has(errors, 'redirect')) {
                $state.target(errors.redirectTo, errors.redirectParams));
                return $state.target(errors.redirect, errors.param); dont work
               return $state.go(errors.redirect, errors.param); wotk fine
            } else {
                return $state.target("test.login");
            }

        }
```